# Where to store (structured) configuration data in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, configuration, heroku

For the Rails 3 application I'm writing, I am considering reading some of the configuration data from XML, YAML or JSON files on the local filesystem.

The point is: *where should I put those files*? Is there any default location in Rails apps where to store this kind of content?

As a side note, my app is deployed on Heroku.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What I always do is:

- If the file is a general configuration file: I create a YAML file in the directory /config with one upper class key per environment
- If I have a file for each environment (big project): I create one YAML per environment and store them in /config/environments/

Then I create an initializer where I load the YAML, I symbolize the keys of the config hash and assign it to a constant like APP_CONFIG

Comment: +1 for this method. [Here's an example of this method](https://gist.github.com/a217834493ff7d727ade) with a couple extra features; it could be easily adopted for the second method (one environment per file).

Answer (score 5):

I will usually adopt this method :

a config/config.yml

```
development:
  another_key: "test"
  app_name: "My App"
test:
  another_key: "test"
production:
  prova: "ciao"
```

then create a ostruct in a initializer

```
#config/initializer/load_config.rb
require 'ostruct'
config = OpenStruct.new(YAML.load_file("#{RAILS_ROOT}/config/config.yml"))
::AppSetting = OpenStruct.new(config.send(RAILS_ENV))
```

No DB table, per environment setup and you could retrive info in a simple way

```
AppSetting.another_key
AppSetting.app_name
```

[here](http://www.viget.com/extend/simple-rails-or-ruby-application-configuration/) a reference
have a nice day!

Answer (score 1):

You can also include it in a model so you can call `Settings.var_name` from anywhere in your app and it will parse the file for the right environment.

With [settingslogic](https://github.com/binarylogic/settingslogic) gem:

```
class Settings < Settingslogic
  source "#{Rails.root}/config/settings.yml"
  namespace Rails.env
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Rails creates a `config` directory by default, containing a lot of configuration info for your application, including the database and environment information. I think that's a logical first place to consider.

A second choice would be the `app` directory, which contains all the models, views and controllers for the application, but I think of that directory as containing executable code and its templates, so I'd go with the `config` directory, personally.